# Laravel Resource gives object instead of value of date format

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel resource to send my api

```
class OfferResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

This gives me (on laravel 5.6) an object:

```
created_at: {
    date: "2018-05-10 18:49:15.000000",
    timezone: "UTC",
    timezone_type: 3
}
```

This is unexpected, beacause on laravel 5.5 I had raw date. However I tried to make protected casts, as mentioned in official documentation:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',  
];
```

and this is not working at all.

Comment: why don't you pass $this->created_at->date in resource

Comment: this is giving error: `"message": "Unknown getter 'date'",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "C:\\www2\\medpraca2\\vendor\\nesbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Carbon.php",
    "line": 955,`

Comment: Did you override the `protected $dates` property?

Comment: @Paul what do you mean?

Comment: You can format it like `'created_at' => $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` when returning from `toArray`.

Comment: @TheAlpha oh, this approach works

Comment: @gileneusz, glad to know that :-)

Comment: @TheAlpha but :) what If I would like to get this object, and format only the data element, to get something like this: `created_at: {date: "10-05-2018", timezone: "UTC", timezone_type: 3}`

Comment: @TheAlpha so why documentation example does not work? BTW, thank you for this tip :) you may post the answer

Comment: I just tried, but it gives me an error: `"message": "Trailing data",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "C:\\www2\\medpraca2\\vendor\\nesbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Carbon.php",
    "line": 775,`

Comment: I'll dig into it :-)

Comment: @TheAlpha thanks! it's very weird experience when documentation example does not work :) especially for newbies like me

Comment: @gileneusz The casting method you did as per the documentation will work if you returned the data directly from the controller without passing it into the resource. Resource will not accept the casting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'created_at' => $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
}
```

Comment: I prefer to cast them to string as when using the format function and the date value is null an exception will be thrown.

`public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at
    ];
}
`

Comment: @Kirkify Nowadays we can use `$this->created_at?->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`